# 'Required request parameter 'id' for method parameter type Integer is present but converted to null'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm creating todo-app with spring-boot.
After adding a task, once I enter a check on checkbox provided next to each todo and then click the done-button, the error  occurs.**'Required request parameter 'id' for method parameter type Integer is present but converted to null'** has occurs.

below is codes.

---

Todo.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "todos")
public class Todo {
@Id
@Nullable
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Nullable
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Integer userId;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "due_date")
private String dueDate;

@Column(name = "priority")
private Integer priority;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "is_completed")
private Boolean isCompleted = false;

public Todo() {

}

public Todo(Integer userId, String title, String description, String dueDate, Integer priority, Boolean isCompleted) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
}
}
```

---

TodoController.java

```
@Controller
public class TodoController {

@Autowired
TodoRepository todoRepository;

@Autowired
TodoService todoService;

@GetMapping("/todo/{id}")
public String home(Model model, User user, Todo todo, @PathVariable("id")Integer id) {

    Integer userId = user.getId();
    if(userId == null) {
        return "redirect:/todo/{id}";
    }
   
    List<Todo> list = todoRepository.find(userId);
    model.addAttribute("list", list);
    model.addAttribute("todo", new Todo(user.getId(), todo.getTitle(), todo.getDescription(), todo.getDueDate(), todo.getPriority(), todo.getIsCompleted()));
    return "home";
}

@PostMapping("/todo/{id}")
public String createTodo(@Validated Todo todo,BindingResult result, User user) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "redirect:/todo/{id}";
    }

    Todo userTodo = new Todo(user.getId(), todo.getTitle(), todo.getDescription(), todo.getDueDate(), todo.getPriority(), todo.getIsCompleted());
    todoService.addTodo(userTodo);
    return "redirect:/todo/{id}";
}

@PostMapping("/todo/update/{id}")
public String doneTodo(@RequestParam(name="id")Integer todoId) {
    Todo updateTodo = todoService.findById(todoId);
    updateTodo.setIsCompleted(true);
    todoService.addTodo(updateTodo);
    return "redirect:/todo/{id}";
}

@PostMapping("/todo/edit/{id}")
public String editTodo() {
    System.out.println("edit");
    return "redirect:/todo/{id}";
}
}
```

---

TodoService.java

```
@Service
public class TodoService {
@Autowired
TodoRepository todoRepository;

public List<Todo> searchAll() {
    return todoRepository.findAll();
}

public void addTodo(Todo todo) {
    todoRepository.save(todo);
}

public Todo findById(Integer id) {
    Optional<Todo> updateTodo = todoRepository.findById(id);
    return updateTodo.orElseGet(updateTodo::get);
}
}
```

---

home.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link th:href="@{/css/home.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Todo</h1>
<div>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/todo/}+${id}" th:object="${todo}">
    <p th:errors="*{title}" class="todo-error-message"></p>
    <input th:field="*{title}" class="add-input" type="text" placeholder="title">
    <input th:field="*{description}" class="add-input" type="text" placeholder="details">
    <input th:field="*{dueDate}" class="add-input-third" type="date"><br/>
    <div class="add-form">
        <span>priority</span>
        <input th:field="*{priority}" type="radio" name="priority" value="3" checked>3
        <input th:field="*{priority}" type="radio" name="priority" value="2">2
        <input th:field="*{priority}" type="radio" name="priority" value="1">1
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="add-btn">add</button>
</form>
</div>

<h2>LIST</h2>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/todo/edit/}+${id}" th:each="list:${list}" th:object="${todo}">
<div th:if="${!todo.isCompleted}">
<input type="checkbox" th:id="${todo.id}" th:value="${todo.id}" th:field="*{isCompleted}" form="done-todo">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" th:value="${list.userId}">
<input type="text" name="title" th:value="${list.title}">
<input type="text" name="description" th:value="${list.description}">
<input type="date" name="dueDate" th:value="${list.dueDate}">
<input type="submit" value="update">
</div>
</form>
<form method="post" id="done-todo" th:action="@{/todo/update/}+${id}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${todo.id}">
<input type="submit" value="done">
</form>

<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    show done todos
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <form class="border p-3" th:action="@{/todo/delete/}+${id}" th:each="todo:${todo}">
        <div th:if="${todo.isCompleted}">
            <input type="text" name="title" th:value="${todo.title}">
            <input type="submit" value="delete">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
<button class="logout-button" type="submit" value="logout">logout</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
 </body>
 </html>
```

---

*What I want to do*

1. I aim to change the value of added todo from false to true after entering a check on checkbox provided next to each todo and then click the done-button.
2. I aim to show todos of which value is true.(true means 'done')

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I couldn't find the way to fix this and I’m so badly stuck at this task.

Comment: Find out what URL is being sent to the server - I would guess perhaps the {id} element in the request is not a valid number. Check logs on the server and/or the browser debugger to see the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. It turns out there is a Service that implements Convert<String, String> (so it will be Convert<Integer, Integer> for your case); which is used not other purpose, not for spring-web, but it got picked up anyway. So I remove the `implements Convert<String, String>` on the Converter bean, then it works.